# Set custom time on bootstrap TimePicker

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i have 2 time pickers in my page like

```
<div class="form-group">
   <input class="time ui-timepicker-input" id="FromTime" name="FromTime" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">            
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <input class="time ui-timepicker-input" id="ToTime" name="FromTime" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off">            
</div>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#ToTime').timepicker();
     $('#FromTime').timepicker();        
 });
```

Now i want to set **ToTime = FromTime + 1 hour**

To raise FromTime value change event and i use the code

```
$('#FromTime').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
   //how to get selected time here
   //set ToTime value with a difference of 1 hour ie if 12:30 am selected set ToTime as 1:30 am
});
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8pD8c/1/ Here is the answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/kW3G7/1121/)

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#FromTime').timepicker({
        defaultTime: false
    });
});
var HoursToAdd = 2;
$('#FromTime').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function (e) {
    var meridian = e.time.meridian
    var hours = e.time.hours
    var minutes = e.time.minutes
    var seconds = e.time.seconds
    var NewTime;
    if (meridian == 'AM') {
        NewTime = new Date('', '', '', hours, minutes, seconds)
    } else if (meridian == 'PM') {
        NewTime = new Date('', '', '', (hours + 12), minutes, seconds)
    }
    NewTime.setHours(NewTime.getHours() + HoursToAdd)
    $('#ToTime').timepicker({
        defaultTime: NewTime.getHours() + " : " + NewTime.getMinutes()
    });
});
```

Comment: Oh sorry i was using jquery timepicker not bootstrap onehttp://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/

Comment: even i am used the same jquery time picker

Comment: Fiddler its is fine 
I can get time via this code 
$('#FromTime').on('changeTime', function() {
console.log($(this).val());
});